# AngularJS - concept understanding view issues (ng-if, ng-switch)

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie tackling AngularJS and JavaScript, and I hope that today I could benefit of an advise from your side. I have an issue with displaying an input block with/without the "readonly" attribute. Created a JSFiddle to explain better my issue, with comments: https://jsfiddle.net/Eugene_Sa/s2tfvL8r/18/

In a nutshell, I have a directive that retrieves a privilege that user has. Based on that directive, the DOM element that contains the 'privilege' attribute is either assigned or removed the 'readonly' status.

The directive sends a request to check if the privilege indicated in the input field is present, and if no, the DOM element is removed, otherwise shown.

The input field looks as follows:

```
<input type="text"
   privilege='has-the-needed-privilege'
   ng-model='vm.tender.view'
   readonly
>
```

Now I have to admit that I could not employ none of the AngularJS features like ng-if or ng-switch in order to solve this problem. Or probably there is a misconception in my head. My questions is how is it possible to make such a selection? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ngReadOnly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) or [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) to make the `input` field either read-only or disabled. Both of these existing directives accept an expression that evaluates to true or false. So, if `ng-readonly="true"`, the field is read-only.

As an example:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.vm = {
    "tender": {
      "view": "test"
    }
  };

  $scope.toggleReadOnly = function() {
    $scope.readOnly = !$scope.readOnly;
  }

  $scope.toggleDisabled = function() {
    $scope.disabled = !$scope.disabled;
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggleReadOnly()">
Toggle Read Only
</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="toggleDisabled()">
Toggle Disabled
</button>
  <input type="text" ng-model='vm.tender.view' ng-readonly="readOnly" ng-disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

If the field is read-only, it'll still look like an ordinary text input field, you just won't be able to change its value. If it's disabled, it'll appear grayed out.

This might eliminate the need for a custom directive. You could just retrieve the value of `privilege` and use that as the expression for `ng-readonly` or `ng-disabled`. In other words, you could set `ng-readonly` or `ng-disabled` to `privilege`.